# Why is my python for loop stopping after 3 iterations?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Secret Santa type of program. The function takes in a list of names as a parameter and is supposed to match each person with another person. No one can be matched with themselves, and each person can only receive and give one gift. It is a simple program so I'll include the entire thing.

```
import random

Game1 = ["Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Eve", "Frank"]

def matchPeople(players):
    needGift = players
    matches = []

    for player in players:
        def getReceiver():
            receiver = random.choice(needGift)
            if receiver == player:
                getReceiver()
            else: 
                matches.append([player, receiver])
                needGift.remove(receiver)
        getReceiver()
    print(matches)

matchPeople(Game1)
```

It is running as expected (I think), except it is stopping after 3 iterations. Upon running the matchPeople() function this is the outcome. I am very new to python (coming from JS), so I'm sure there is a logical explanation. However! I do not know what it is...

```
[['Alice', 'Charlie'], 
 ['Bob', 'David'], 
 ['Eve', 'Bob']]
```

Comment: You're modifying the list you're iterating over when you do `needGift.remove(receiver)`.

Comment: If `needGift` should be a copy of `players`, use `needGift = players.copy()`

Comment: Don't use recursion to implement a possibly infinite loop.

Comment: Instead of recursion, you can use (assuming a recent version of Python): `while (receiver := random.choice(needGift)) == player: pass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that `needGift` and `players` refer to the *same* object in memory - and when you remove elements from it inside your nested function, they are also removed from the player list.

The change listed bellow will make `needGift` a copy of the `players` list (by taking a "slice" starting at the begging and proceeding to the end of it - the default slice values when you suppress the indexes around the `:`)

change

`needGift = players`

to

`needGift = players[:]`